# Selecting first instance of class but not nested instances via jQuery

Tags: jquery

Given the following hypothetical markup:

```
<ul class="monkey">
    <li>
        <p class="horse"></p>
        <p class="cow"></p>
    </li>
</ul>

<dl class="monkey">
    <dt class="horse"></dt>
    <dd class="cow">
        <dl>
            <dt></dt>
            <dd></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="monkey">
            <dt class="horse"></dt>
            <dd class="cow"></dd>
        </dl>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I want to be able to grab the 'first level' of horse and cow classes within each monkey class. But I don't want the NESTED horse and cow classes.

I started with .children, but that won't work with the UL example as they aren't direct children of .monkey.

I can use find: $('.monkey').find('.horse, .cow') but that returns all instances, including the nested ones.

I can filter the find: $('.monkey').find('.horse, .cow').not('.cow .horse, .cow .cow') but that prevents me from selecting nested instances on a second function call.

So...I guess what I'm looking for is 'find first "level" of this descendant'.
I could likely do this with some looping logic, but was wondering if there is a selector and/or some combo of selectors that would achieve that logic.

UPDATE:

Here's what I ended up with:

```
$('.monkey')
    .children('.cow')
        ...do something...
    .end()
    .children('li')
        .children('.cow')
            ...do something...
        .end()
    .end()
```

Seems verbose/hacky but seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the children, as it give you the immediate child elements.

```
$(".monkey").children(".horse, .cow, li > .horse, li > .cow")
```

Edited

```
$(".monkey, .monkey > li").children(".horse, .cow")
```

Comment: that's a good point. I suppose I could just decide that either they need to be direct children or grandchildren and leave it at that. That might be the best option.

Comment: Hmm...well, it appears that descendant selectors don't work within a children() traversal.

Comment: well try the modified version above

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.monkey .horse:first')
```

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: :first returns the first element. Not a set of elements at that 'first' descendant level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$('.monkey>.horse, .monkey>.cow')
```

That should select just immediate children of .monkey, and you can filter out which .monkey object you want.

Comment: This will return the nested elements as well.

Comment: The issue is that I am attaching the chain initially to the '.monkey' query. I'd rather not traverse the DOM a second time to get the children.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct selector that will allow you to return only the first children of both **li** and **dt** elements

```
var selection = $(".monkey > * > .horse, .monkey > * > .cow");
```