# jQuery find first level elements with a class but not nested elements inside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is the example HTML (ids will not be present, added here for demo purpose)

```html
<div id="root" class="node">
    <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
        <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
            <div class="node" id="n0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="node" id="n1"></div>
        <div class="node" id="n2"></div>
        <div class="node" id="n3"></div>
        <div class="node" id="n4">
            <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
                <div class="node" id="n4_1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
                <div class="node" id="n4_2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="node" id="n5"></div>
    <div class="node" id="n6"></div>
    <div class="node" id="n7"></div>
    <div class="node" id="n8">
        <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
            <div class="node" id="n8_1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
            <div class="node" id="n8_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Find first level nodes within the root using a function:

```js
function findNextLevelNodes($elem) {
    // example code
    let selector = '[selector to include next nodes, but not nodes nested within those]';
    $elem.find(selector).each((i, node) => console.log($(node).attr('id')));
}
```

such that

```js
let $root = $('#root');
findNextLevelNodes($root);
// should print n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8
// should not print n4_1, n4_2, n8_1, n8_2
```

Seems simple enough but I can't find the selector that will get me this result.

Found similar questions, but was not satisfied with answers, surely this should be easy enough to do, **without manually looping through all of the children**

***Similar questions -***

[jQuery find only not nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218483/jquery-find-only-not-nested-elements)

- this has a solution that relies on looping through all elements inside `#root`
- `node` can be nested to any level, so I would prefer if I didn't have to recursively loop through each and every element inside `#root`

[Selecting first instance of class but not nested instances via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782165/selecting-first-instance-of-class-but-not-nested-instances-via-jquery?rq=1)

- answers depend on the classes/tags of non-node elements of html, so not applicable

**EDIT**

`findNextLevelNodes` needs to be efficient in my case since it would be called recursively for each child node, and if `findNextLevelNodes` itself has recursion through all children, or `.parents` call, I have a feeling it might not be efficient with large `node` trees

For now it seems, i'll have to alter the html classes to keep things efficient, kinda like

```html
<div id="root" class="node l0">
    <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
        <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
            <div class="node l1" id="n0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="node l1" id="n1"></div>
        <div class="node l1" id="n2"></div>
        <div class="node l1" id="n3"></div>
        <div class="node l1" id="n4">
            <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
                <div class="node l2" id="n4_1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
                <div class="node l2" id="n4_2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="node l1" id="n5"></div>
    <div class="node l1" id="n6"></div>
    <div class="node l1" id="n7"></div>
    <div class="node l1" id="n8">
        <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
            <div class="node l2" id="n8_1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="[any class that is not `node`]">
            <div class="node l2" id="n8_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
// now this should work
function findNextLevelNodes($root, level) {
    return $root.find('.node.l' + level);
}
```

Seems a bit hacky, I'll wait for sometime to see if I find anything more elegant and decently efficient, otherwise will have to go with this.

Answer (score 2):

you can reach that simply by using a `recursive` function that will search in direct node child using [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/), if it have a class "node" then go to next direct child otherwise go deep again
Here is the function

```
function findNextLevelNodesByClass($elem, className) {

  let nodesArray = [];
  
  function getRecursiveNextDom($rootNode) {
    $rootNode.children().each((i, elemnt) => {
      if ($(elemnt).hasClass(className))
        nodesArray.push(elemnt)
      else
        getRecursiveNextDom($(elemnt));
    })
  }
  
  
  getRecursiveNextDom($elem,className);
  
  return nodesArray;
}
```

See working snippet :

```js
function findNextLevelNodesByClass($elem, className) {

  let nodesArray = [];
  
  function getRecursiveNextDom($rootNode) {
    $rootNode.children().each((i, elemnt) => {
      if ($(elemnt).hasClass(className))
        nodesArray.push(elemnt)
      else
        getRecursiveNextDom($(elemnt));
    })
  }
  
  
  getRecursiveNextDom($elem,className);
  
  return nodesArray;
}


let $root = $('#root');
let result = findNextLevelNodesByClass($root, 'node');
//result.forEach( element => console.log(element.id))
console.log( result.map(function(y){return y.id}).join(','))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" class="node">
  <div class="anyclass">
    <div class="anyclass">
      <div class="node" id="n0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="node" id="n1"></div>
    <div class="node" id="n2"></div>
    <div class="node" id="n3"></div>
    <div class="node" id="n4">
      <div class="anyclass">
        <div class="node" id="n4_1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="anyclass">
        <div class="node" id="n4_2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="node" id="n5"></div>
  <div class="node" id="n6"></div>
  <div class="node" id="n7"></div>
  <div class="node" id="n8">
    <div class="anyclass">
      <div class="node" id="n8_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="anyclass">
      <div class="node" id="n8_2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited my question with my concern with using recursive calls, since `findNextLevelNodes` is intended to be used recursively itself, i'll look around for a better solution for a bit more, It doesn't seem like there are any better solutions though

Comment: okey ,with this solution you don't matter to add extra class of level , it'll work in all cases whether deep node level or not :)

Answer (score 2):

i dont see others solutions than: from all `.node`, i am filtering `.node` that have only 1 parent `.node` (root at least)

```
$('#root .node').filter( (s,e) => $(e).parents(".node").length < 2); // or length == 1
```

i have written < 2 because *root has a class node*, else set < 1.

you could write too:

```
$('#root').find(".node").filter( (s,e) => $(e).parents(".node").length < 2);
```

or

```
$('.node').filter( (s,e) => $(e).parents(".node").length == 1);
```

if you add class indicating level,

`$("#root .node.l1")` will give you the result..and will be the more efficient

Comment: Edited my question with my concern with using `.parents` call, i'll look around for a better solution for a bit more, It doesn't seem like there are any better solutions though, Thanks for the help

Comment: if the search html  is an element important for you i suggest you to build your html in this sense.. for example create id with level inside..